# Accessing methods, actions and/or outlets from other controllers with swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, xcode9-beta, nssplitview

I'm working on a macOS project where I have a split view containing 2 other ViewControllers and I can't figure out how to access the ViewControllers from my primary window's ViewController.

this is the setup:

[image: screenshot of storyboard]

Basically what I'm trying to do is use the `Button` in my `ViewController` on the top-left to access the `Label` in my `SectionController` on the right, which is embedded in my split view.

Since I can't create an `IBAction` or `IBOutlet` for a control in a different ViewController, I can't figure out how to get these to be connected. My current workaround has been to have a property on my `AppDelegate` and then access the main shared application delegate, but that feels hacky and won't scale. I'm completely lost as to how to proceed. I'm ok with using a function to pass data or whatever to the other ViewController(s).

I'm using Swift 4 with Xcode 9 (beta).

Any ideas?

Comment: "Since I can't create an IBAction or IBOutlet for a control in a different ViewController"  Create a view controller subclass for each split.  If you work for Apple, Inc. then why don't you ask your colleague?

Comment: each split already has a ViewController subclass and that's where I'm adding some functions/actions/properties, but have no way to reach that from my top-level view. Is there something else I'm missing? Re apple: it's a large company, I don't have any devs that work in xcode/swift/cocoa in my division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can't create IBAction or IBOutlet for a control in a different ViewController!!
But simply each view controller in the hierarchy has a reference for its child view controllers.

**Method 1:**

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    let splitViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! YourSplitViewController
    let targetViewController = splitViewController.childViewControllers[0] as! YourTargetViewController
    targetViewController.label.text = "Whatever!"
}
```

**Method 2:**

It may be better if you took a reference for each child controller in your "prepare for segue" method

ContainerViewController:

```
var mySplitViewController: YourSplitViewController?
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "splitViewSegue" {
        self.mySplitViewController = segue.destination as! YourSplitViewController
    }
}
```

YourSplitViewController:

```
var aViewController: YourFirstViewController?
var bViewController: YourSecondViewController?
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "aViewSegue" {
        self.aViewController = segue.destination as! YourFirstViewController
    } else if segue.identifier == "bViewSegue" {
        self.bViewController = segue.destination as! YourSecondViewController
    }
}
```

So you can access it like that in your container view controller:

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.mySplitViewController.firstViewController.label.text = "Whatever!"
}
```

Comment: do I need to subclass the NSSplitViewController in order to do this? I was noticing that I because the split view was embedded in a Container View that it wasn't visible as a `childViewController` from my top-level view and it wasn't visible as a `parent` from the bottom views. I think there's something minor that I'm missing with how I'm wiring this up.

Comment: ok, fiddling with the info you gave me, I think I figured out what's going on (I never dealt with segues before). I'll dabble, but this has put me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: for method 1 you don't have to subclass UISplitViewController, You can just call it through childViewControllers property

Comment: You can just reach what you want with this short way:

let splitViewController = self.childViewControllers[0] as! UISplitViewController;
    let targetViewController = splitViewController.childViewControllers[0] as! YourTargetViewController;
    targetViewController.label.text = "Whatever!";

Comment: this worked! thanks! I'm trying to understand why it doesn't work unless I create a subclass of `NSSplitViewController`. I literally put no code in the subclass and this works, if I don't subclass it, I get nothing from `.childViewControllers`. But it works, so I'm not complaining.